# How to place items relatively in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Consider I have a `<div style="margin-top:50px">` and I need to places items in it relatively. There are some elements above `<div>`. For example, I have a `<input type="text" />` and a button. I need to place this at the bottom of the `<div>` with text input being on left side aligned to parent and and button aligned to right of the parent. The input text must fill the width to button. I dont want to hardcode the `px` or `em`.

How do I achieve this ?

Edit: This is how it must look like.

[image: Sample]

Now I dont want to specify the length of text input. What I want is the button to be rendered to the right bottom of div and text input must set its width accordingly so as to fill space.

Comment: Have you considered drawing a quick picture to show what this must look like?

Comment: @thirtydot has a point. Adding the markup would entail maybe 4 lines of code?

Comment: @thirtydot: I have added an image of the alignments I need.

Answer (score 1):

Ha! where was the drawing the first time around?

http://jsfiddle.net/eGHjs/

(Looks almost identical in IE7, Chrome, FF).

Comment: Just an FYI, the input box overflows out of the parent in your demo on Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome's default border is pushing it out. Thanks.

Comment: Use 70%/29% width, so that the sum is less than 100%. There is a browser specific margin, border and padding around input elements, so when you target 100% width, the actual width becomes 100% + 2x2xmargin + 2x2xborder + 2x2xpadding.

Comment: @Salman - The css in the fiddle should have eliminated those caveats. Do you have a browser that's producing a +100 combined width?

Comment: Ah, no actually. But just in case someone is not using a CSS `reset`. Also, IE7 does not understand the `outline` attribute so the input appears without any sort of border.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least hardcode the button width to achive that.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bottom">
        <div><input type="text" class="text"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
</div>

div#container {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#bottom div {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 105px;
}

#container #bottom input.text { 
    width: 100%;
}

#submit {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But like I said, I dont want to specify px or em. In the above code button width is fixed to 100px.

Comment: Then you'll have to use javascript. Read the button width after the document is loaded/resized and set the text field width accordingly. or go ugly with a table.

Comment: If you dont want px or em, is % fine? so set the button width to 9% and the div around the input to 90% (remove the margin). Never mind, I don't think there is a stackpanel solution with first-fill in HTML/CSS.

Comment: I tried with % earlier but it looks weird on some screens. I am designing for multiple screens. So that causes an issue